# How to change the size of Tab item in Xamarin.forms

Tags: xamarin.forms, tabbedpage

I have created a `TabbedPage` using data template. And its working fine in all 3 platforms (iOS,Android and UWP). In UWP app, Tab sizes are not consumes the screen width.

[image]

In here you can see the last tab has extra spaces. How can I make the tabs according to the screen width size? Also this should work for any screen size and landscape and portrait as well.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure why you don't use the default tabbed page which is working fine and tested on each platform.

You also have options like customizing the tabbed page with custom renderers and of course multiple plugins are available already.

Despite all of that, if you want to continue with what you have, you can use: **FillAndExpand** in the Horizontal options of whatever layout you are using.

A new layout is also very interesting in Xamarin forms 3.0 called FlexLayout which provide many sizing and alignment options